# Custom validator on associated model make other Rspec model tests break

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, shoulda

I have 2 models sharing a simple belong_to/has_many relation: Room belongs to Building

I created a custom validator called total_number_rooms_limited_to_15 that ensures I can't create more than 15 rooms for a given Building.

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base

    # -- Relationships --------------------------------------------------------
  belongs_to :admin_user,     :foreign_key => 'admin_user_id'
  belongs_to :building,        :foreign_key => 'building_id'

  # -- Validations ----------------------------------------------------------              

  validates :room_filename,
              presence: true             

  # associated models primary key validates 
  validates :admin_user_id,
     presence: true
  validates :building_id,
     presence: true  

  validate :total_number_rooms_limited_to_15

  private

    def total_number_rooms_limited_to_15
      errors[:base] <<  "There can't be more than 15 rooms. There are already 15 .
                        <br/>Please remove another one or drop trying adding this one.".html_safe 
          unless ( self.building.rooms.count < 15 )
    end
```

But the problem is that after creating this new validator, all my "usual" basic tests fail.

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Room, type: :model do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = {
      room_filename:                               "xyz" 
    }
  end  

  # -- Models Tests --------------------------------------------------------
  describe "tests on ST's models validations for room_filename" do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:room_filename) }    
    it { is_expected.not_to allow_value(" ").for(:room_filename) }    
  end
```

All give me the following error message:

```
1) Room tests on ST's models validations for room_filename should validate that :room_filename cannot be empty/falsy
     Failure/Error:
       errors[:base] <<  "There can't be more than 15 rooms. There are already 15 .
                         <br/>Please remove another one or drop trying adding this one.".html_safe unless ( self.building.rooms.count < 15 )

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `rooms' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried adding inside @attr the attribute a associated "virtual" building but it not work out;, getting the same error message:

```
before(:each) do
    @attr = {
      room_filename:                               "xyz",
      building_id:                                 1
    }
```

**ADDED INFO**

```
config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, :except => %w(roles)) 
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Comment: Are you deleting everything in the database before each test in run?

Comment: looks like `self.rooms.count` self is nil? What is `self`?

Comment: @kris: I set this up a long time ago but I think yes. I'll add a gist that might be useful from my spec_helper right now

Comment: well this method is inside my file models/room.rb so self is a Room. my method uses self.building.rooms.count => so self is the current room then self.building goes to find the building which the room belongs to and self.building.rooms.count goes to count all the rooms from the latter.

Comment: Your error mentions `self.rooms.count < 15` while your sample code says `self.building.rooms.count < 15`. Which is correct?

Comment: Edited it. The right one is self.building.rooms.count. Sorry for mistyping/copying my original code.

Answer (score 1):

For custom validations you'll need to instantiate a new `Room` object in your tests. If you don't have something like `factory_girl` or `fabrication` in place to create objects for your test, you can do this:

```
before(:each) do
  @admin_user = AdminUser.create!(...attributes)
  @building = Building.create!(...attributes)
  @room = Room.create!(building_id: @building.id, admin_user_id: @admin_user.id)
end
```

Then make sure you're calling your validation on the instance instead of your `Room` class:

```
def total_number_rooms_limited_to_15
  errors[:base] <<  "There can't be more...".html_safe 
  unless ( building.present? && building.rooms.count < 15 )
end
```

Comment: thanks. I'm using Factory_girl(not here in this precise test, but I could use it). Will try tomorrow.